# Facing ssl connection issue between two services in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, istio-gateway

I am trying to establsih a ssl connection between two services in same namesapce.I have istio-proxy side car container embedded in every pod.I have created the peerauthentication and destination rules.

Destination rule

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
spec:
  host: brand-tool-ui-clone
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      privateKey: /etc/istio/private/mykey.key
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/certs/mycert.crt
```

Peerauthentication

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: PeerAuthentication
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-01-27T12:48:19Z"
  generation: 2
  name: default
  namespace: https-poc
  resourceVersion: "128521847"
  uid: 9035144f-4ae5-4b2e-89af-c14fc081b96a
spec:
  mtls:
    mode: PERMISSIVE
```

but not able to call other service successfully using https, getting this error from curl

```
$ curl -k  -v https://<hostname>/ecv-status
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x5597ba492680)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x5597ba492680)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x5597ba492680)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x5597ba492680)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x5597ba492680)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x5597ba492680)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x5597ba492680)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x5597ba492680)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x5597ba492680)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x5597ba492680)
*   Trying 1.199.124.123...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x5597ba492680)
* Connected to <host> (1.199.124.123) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

UPDATE

After updating the destination rule and peerauthentication as per the comment and I am now getting alert certificate reuqired.

```
*   Trying 1.199.124.123:443...
* Connected to <host> (1.199.124.123) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: [NONE]
*  start date: Jan 30 11:30:37 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 31 11:32:37 2023 GMT
*  issuer: O=cluster.local
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate in certificate chain (19), continuing anyway.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55f415ab6b80)
> GET /ecv-status HTTP/2
> Host: <host>
> user-agent: curl/7.79.1
> accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, unknown (628):
* OpenSSL SSL_read: error:1409445C:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv13 alert certificate required, errno 0
* Failed receiving HTTP2 data
* OpenSSL SSL_write: SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN, errno 0
* Failed sending HTTP2 data
* Connection #0 to host  left intact
curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: error:1409445C:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv13 alert certificate required, errno 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The attributes used in DestinationRule has to be corrected with "clientCertificate".  Request you to refer [istio official documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ClientTLSSettings) which has proper example and allowed values for destination rule.

The istio mTLS communication (ISTIO_MUTUAL) feature can be utilized instead of maintain by deployment, where istio will take care loading the necessary certificates in all the pods and ensure the communication is secure. Below is the destination rule which can be created for all services

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: ratings-istio-mtls
spec:
  host: <service-name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
```

And change PeerAuthentication mtls mode to "STRICT"  which will ensure TWO-WAY communication between pods.

Comment: `spec:
  exportTo:
  - .
  host: brand-tool-ui-clone.https-poc.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      clientCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/brand.stg.walmart.com.crt
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/brand.stg.walmart.com.key
`

Comment: if "ISTIO_MUTUAL" is used in desitnation rule in that case no need of having clientCertificate and privateKey attributes.